# How do I obtain a list of compound words as nouns?

Tags: nouns, compounds

How do I obtain a list of compound words as nouns?

Example: *polar bear*. I can only detect *polar* as an adjective and *bear* as a noun. But *polar bear* is actually a noun. How do I obtain a free list of such?

Another example is *hot dog*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/).  Together with the associated relationship information you can get for WordNet in RDF format you would get the following information for 'polar bear':

```
wn30:synset-ice_bear-noun-1
white bear of Arctic regions
Synonyms Thalarctos maritimus, Ursus Maritimus, ice bear
--type--> wn30:synset-bear-noun-1
--memberMeronymOf--> wn30:synset-Thalarctos-noun-1
```

Following the Type relation further would also reveal that it's a Mammal, and an Animal

One way to try Wordnet is on my [the demo page for my Natural Language Engine](https://nlp.abodit.com/Demo/Demo.html).  Simply type 'define' and then the word you want to look up.  (P.S. It may take a few seconds to restart if nobody has been there recently.)

Comment: Ian, thanks for your help. What tool did you use? I used java version of the WordNet library. I can only load nouns,adjs,advs for now...not sure how I detect something like what you did.

Comment: I used the RDF version of WordNet.  Parsed that, built an in memory graph, added my own conjugations for verbs, plurals for nouns, ... "polar bear" is in the basic Wordnet files, you just need a parser that can handle the ambiguity that exists throughout the English language.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Which file you used from Wordnet to parse out "polar bear" and "hot dog"? I think I found it from data.noun, but I am not sure if it is. Also, a grep on all the files in 'dict' directory, didn't find "dim sum"

Comment: "wn30:synset-dim_sum-noun-1" is in wordnet-glossary.ttl which is part of the RDF version

Comment: Ian: I found a page at http://nlp.abodit.com/home/demo.html that appears to claim to be a demo of the Abodit Natural Language Engine.  (1) http://nlp.abodit.com/home/demo doesn’t redirect there.  (2) I say that “it appears to claim to be a demo of the” NLE because, AFAICT, it’s totally non-functional.  I can’t get anything to happen, even if I click in the menus or the “chat” button.  (3) If the browser window isn’t big enough to display the entire page, your bottom bar obscures the bottom 48 pixels of the page — I can’t scroll it into view. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3b) Should I conclude from the “2011-2016” copyright notice that this is ‘‘abandonware’’?

Comment: @Scott Outdated link is now fixed, thanks for pointing that out. Not sure why that old file is still on the server, will get it deleted, hazard of hosting pages on S3 I guess.

Comment: Ian: (1) Thanks for responding.  (2) I still can’t get the new Demo page to work in Internet Explorer.  Is that a known (or unsurprising) limitation, or do I have something configured wrong?  (It works in Firefox.)  (3) Perhaps I’m just dumb, but I don’t see how anything you’ve said or written answers the question: “How do I obtain a list of compound words as nouns?”  Don’t knock yourself out explaining it to me; frankly, I don’t really care.  You might want to think about whether you’ve communicated your answer clearly enough for a random, average person to understand.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) I just noticed that https://nlp.abodit.com/Home/License.html links to http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/license/, which doesn’t exist.  There is a page at https://wordnet.princeton.edu/license-and-commercial-use.  (5) I spent a few minutes playing with the demo.  I use the word ‘‘playing’’ deliberately; I’m dumb, so I don’t know what I’m doing.  I was puzzled by the responses for “Christmas” and “Easter”.  It seems to believe that Christmas runs from December 20 until (or through) January 1.  I say “until (or through)” because its use of the word “midnight”  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  is somewhat ambiguous.  Note that these are not the traditional “twelve days of Christmas” (that would be December 25 until January 6).  Easter is two days before (Good Friday) until two days after (Easter Monday or Easter Tuesday?).  For both Christmas and Easter, it says that you can query for it using the SQL expression ```true```, which, of course, is a glitch.  (0) Please either take my comments as constructive criticism, or just ignore them.  I tend to rant.

Comment: @Scott Maybe take this offline to the email on the website. Briefly, if you can't do it in SQL (e.g. Easter), relatively easily it returns true and you have to filter client-side.